# Make text follow the shape of a tape node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using a node with `tape` shape. How can the make the text inside the node follow the shape, i.e. going up and down like the boarder?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[tape,draw=black](a){Text and more Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A suggestion here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-version-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the decoration `text along path`, where the path is constructed using the `sin` and `cos` path constructions in such a way that it follows the contour of the shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytext{Text and more Text}
\node[tape,draw=black](a){\phantom{\mytext}};
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text=\mytext,text align=center,raise=-3pt}] (a.-180) sin ($(a.-150)!0.5!(a.150)$) cos (a.center)
sin ($(a.-30)!0.5!(a.30)$) cos (a.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!!!!!!